# how to find the all column value between start and end date? excepted output

Tags: mysql

I run the query

```
SELECT * FROM roomcalendar where day between '2016-08-25' and '2016-08-28'
```

the result show in the following image.

[image]

but i want to find the value 1 of all `avaroom` between '2016-08-25' and '2016-08-28'

if i use like this

```
SELECT * FROM roomcalendar where day between '2016-08-25' and '2016-08-28' and NOT avaroom=0
```

it shows 1 row

i need to check all the `avaroom = 0` beteewn start and end date.

How to do it?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you share the result you'd like to get?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM roomcalendar where day between '2016-08-25' and '2016-08-28' AND avaroom <> 0;` is this what you want? Having said that, the question is vague.

Comment: i need it use between 25 and 26 it show the one result. and when i use 25 and 28 it will be show no result

Comment: @iMan basically it right but it will be work between 25 to 26. if we use 25 to 28 it will be no result right?.. please check it in image . Thanks.

Comment: @MinKoKo If you get a result for 25 to 26, then you will get **at least** the same result for date between 25 and anything above 26. Can you update the question with 'excepted output'?

Comment: @iManYes i update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is what do you want as a result?

```
SELECT 'YES' as Column_Name
FROM roomcalendar
WHERE day between '2016-08-25' and '2016-08-28'
  AND avaroom <> 0
```

This will return `YES` if there are any records with avaroom <> 0 , and NULL if not.

If you want to select **all** but only if no avaroom <> 0 exists, then :

```
SELECT * FROM roomcalendar t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM roomcalendar s
                 WHERE s.day between '2016-08-25' and '2016-08-28'
                   AND s.avaroom <> 0)
 AND t.day between '2016-08-25' and '2016-08-28'
```

Comment: It show error bro. 3 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "NOT" at position 36)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "EXISTS" at position 40)
Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 46)

Comment: A) I don't have the keyword `NOT` in my answer. B) this query is perfectly fine for MySQL . Are you sure you are using MySQL ?

Comment: u use NOT EXISTS. if i remove NOT keywork it work but i same as my query. Thanks bro. please check it. You use not near the where

Comment: Are you using MySQL ?

Comment: Upgrade your version of MySQL .

Comment: Thanks bro , i update and run it show 0 result when i use the start date 25 and 26. i think it will be one result

Comment: Please provide your expected output of this query. Then I'll know what you are trying to do.

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39146124/hotel-booking-check-empty-room-between-arrival-date-and-departure-date