# hotel booking check empty room between arrival date and departure date?

Tags: mysql

Basically i retrieve all available room with arrival and departure date from the room table.

SQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM `roomcalendar` where day BETWEEN '2016-08-25' and '2016-08-31'
```

Result is

```
id day        roomname avaroom
 1 2016-08-25 RoomA          0
 2 2016-08-26 RoomA          2
 3 2016-08-27 RoomA          0
 4 2016-08-28 RoomA          1
 5 2016-08-29 RoomA          1
 6 2016-08-30 RoomA          0
 7 2016-08-31 RoomA          1
```

I just want available room if avaroom not equal to 0 beteen arrival date and departure date

And I want the result

SQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM `roomcalendar` where day BETWEEN '2016-08-25' and '2016-08-31'
```

it must be empty result

SQL Query

```
 SELECT * FROM `roomcalendar` where day BETWEEN '2016-08-25' and '2016-08-26'
```

it must be empty result

SQL Query

```
 SELECT * FROM `roomcalendar` where day BETWEEN '2016-08-26' and '2016-08-27'
```

it show one result

SQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM `roomcalendar` where day BETWEEN '2016-08-26' and '2016-08-28'
```

it must be empty result

SQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM `roomcalendar` where day BETWEEN '2016-08-28' and '2016-08-30'
```

it show two result

Thanks.

Comment: Mmmmm... `and avaroom  <> 0` ?

Comment: regarding your last example: why two results if on 2016-08-30 avaroom is 0?

Comment: @Hackerman if we use avaroom <> 0 it show three reuslt. but i need empty. SELECT * FROM `roomcalendar` where day BETWEEN '2016-08-25' and '2016-08-31' and avaroom <> 0

Comment: @arilia Yes the last query is working but other are false. i need to all pass! Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more about the meaning of the `avaroom` field?

Comment: avaroom mean available room for searching room with start and end date.

Comment: What is the meaning of the values in `avaroom`? 0 = not available, 1 = available? What does "2" means?

Comment: This is a really strange schema. Nobody stores room availability!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want available room if avaroom not equal to 0 beteen arrival date and departure date

So if you reformulate this:

- you want the room if there is no row where `avaroom` = 0 between two dates.

Translated in SQL:

```
select * from roomcalendar
where day between '2016-08-25' and '2016-08-31'
and not exists (
  select * from roomcalendar
  where day between '2016-08-25' and '2016-08-31'
  and avaroom = 0
);
```

You can also reformulate by saying:

- you want the room if the number of rows where avaroom is not 0 is the total number of rows expected (in this case, this corresponds to the amount of days)

Translated in SQL:

```
select * from roomcalendar
where day between '2016-08-25' and '2016-08-31'
and avaroom != 0
having count(*) = datediff('2016-08-31','2016-08-25') + 1
```

You might have to tweak the queries a bit, but that should point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the query like this.

```
SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE `room_id` = '1' 
AND booking_end >= '2020-12-01 13:20:00' AND booking_start <= '2020-12-10 13:20:00'
```